# how to connect multi k8s namespaces to the same PV?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-efs

On my k8s i would like to run 3 namespace with the same PV. currently i have one namespace setup how do i configure namespace2 and namespace3?

**pv.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: efs-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: fs-<582a03f3>
```

**claim.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: efs-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

**storageclass.yaml**

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: efs-sc
provisioner: efs.csi.aws.com
```

Answer (score 1):

PVC can be put in different namespaces by setting metadata.namespace but PV cannot. PVC will pre-bind to the PV with the same name. My solution is just name PV&PVC pair with different for each name space,eg. efs-pv-namespace1, efs-pv-namespace2.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-caelus
  namespace: caelus
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 15Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-caelus
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 15Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 10.100.15.163
    path: "/"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: nfs-nirvana
  namespace: nirvana
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: ""
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 15Gi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs-nirvana
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 15Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: 10.100.15.163
    path: "/"
```